# Disable File Path History In Windows Explorer 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

If I manually enter a file path in windows explorer, that file path will stay in the drop down unless I manually clear it. What I want to do is completely disable the path from being saved in the first place. Does anyone know if that is possible

Comment: Here you go: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/131023-windows-explorer-auto-suggest-delete-typed-paths.html

Comment: @jatin Your link deletes my history not prevents the history from being formed.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Windows+R</kbd>, then paste the following into the `Open` field:

```
reg.exe ADD HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoComplete /v AutoSuggest /t REG_SZ /d no /f
```

and click `OK`

This turns off the auto suggest feature, I'm not sure it turns off the history itself. You could try turning it off, using Explorer for a while and turning it back on checking whether you are offered recent items in the drop-down.

Comment: Confirmed working with Windows 10.  Does not require reboot.

Comment: Does not seem to work with Win 10 for me. Paths which are entered via keyboard (i.e. "C:\I_Typed_This" still get added to the address bar history. Paths which are entered via mouse click do not get stored in that history. It's easy to clear the history by right clicking on the address bar. I can't figure out how to *disable* that history.